# Как сделать правильно синтаксический разбор?

Tags: синтаксис

Апрельский сон с его улыбкой маю. Помогите, пожалуйста, " с его улыбкой маю"будет сказуемым? Или "с улыбкой" и "маю" - дополнение? Или определение?

В назывных предложениях: аллеи рек; зеркальности озер и т.д. слова "рек" и "озер" являются приложениями, или эти словосочетания и есть подлежащие?

Answer (score 2):

По определению,

назывные предложения – это односоставные предложения с главным членом – подлежащим.

> Назывные предложения могут быть нераспространёнными и состоять только
>   из одного слова – главного члена либо распространенными, включающими
>   другие члены предложения...

Я думаю (но не уверена) что у нас два определения к подлежащему-существительному *сон* - согласованное (апрельский) и несогласованное (с улыбкой); маю - дополнение.

А  в *аллеях рек, зеркальностях озёр* реки и озёра - дополнения, отвечающие на вопрос *чего?*

Comment: Галина, в назывных предложениях не может быть дополнения. Т.к. дополнение всегда зависит от сказуемого.

Comment: Сержик, спасибо! Я в теории не сильна, а образцов разбора не нашла.

Answer (score 0):

Апрельский сон с его улыбкой маю

Что?-сон

Какой?-апрельский, с улыбкой -определения

с улыбкой какой?-его-определение
с улыбкой какой?кому?- маю - определение с оттенком дополнения

аллеи (какие?чего?)рек; зеркальности (какие? чего?)озер - определения с оттенком дополнения